# iOS what element is most suitable for large texts eg text view

Tags: ios, user-interface

I wonder what ui element I should use for large sets of text. Eg anything between 200 - 1000 characters.

I already place the text inside a scrollview so it doesn't have to ve scrollable or editable etc, I just want to display text.

So what should I use between label / text view / text field?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text views are good for texts with varying lengths, but they have a scroll view of their own. You may consider using a normal UILabel and setting the "Lines" property to 0. I know that sounds strange, but setting it to 0 tells the label that it is a multi-line label. Then you can use auto layout to establish the width of the UILabel. It will grow down based on the amount of text in it. Text fields would be inappropriate for displaying texts in most cases; they are better for user input.

Comment: Thanks, but I saw that I can disable scrolling for text views, so is there any other difference between labels and text views? Eg a limit on how many characters a label can hold?

Comment: @KiwoTew Text views and labels do look different from one another (e.g. text views' content box is inset a bit from the edge of the text view container), but of course you can customize the font and size of the text in both. With a multi-line label there is no limit on how many characters it can hold, so it's just like a text view in that way. If you enable scrolling in the text view, however, it is quite different from a label because you can, well, scroll. :-)